# How do I sort IList C # by date?

Tags: c#, winforms, list, linq, sorting

I have an IList:

```
IList[] info = new IList[2];
info[0] = Date;      //List<DateTime> item
info[1] = something; //List<double> item
```

So, I want sort `info` by dates in `info[0]`. Like that:

```
 Date.Sort((a, b) => a.CompareTo(b));
```

But when i'm trying to do it:

```
IEnumerable[] sortedEnum = info.OrderBy(info[0].Sort((a, b) => a.CompareTo(b)));
```

I get:

> 'System.Collections.IList' does not contain a definition for 'Sort' and no extension method 'Sort' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.IList' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

Can someoene help me with this?

Comment: Why do you use *obsolete* `IList` and `IEnumerable`? Change them to `IList<Object>` and `IEnumeratble<Object>`

Comment: So... you have an array of lists - are you trying to sort the array? or are you actually trying to sort the two lists, keeping the two in sync?

Comment: That doesn’t even make sense. How would you sort a list of items by one item in that list? Also, LINQ doesn’t work on non-generic `IList`s. If you have a `IList<T>`, then it’s just `info.OrderBy(x => x.DateProperty)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is an X/Y problem. You're trying to solve a complex "sort two lists congruent to each-other". And ... you can *do* that, but it is very hard. `Array.Sort` has a suitable method for sorting two *arrays* in connection, but: not lists. You *could* try and do that, but frankly I think you're solving the wrong problem. If each `DateTime` and `double` is logically connected, then *rather* than having two lists: have *one* list with a composite value. For example:

```
var list = new List<(DateTime when, double value)>();
list.Add((dateX, valueX)); // your values...
list.Add((dateY, valueY));
list.Add((dateZ, valueZ));

list.Sort((x,y) => x.when.compareTo(y.when));
```

Here I'm using tuple-types, but the same thing can be done by declaring your own type to hold the composite values. You might also want to look into pre-sorted list container types, but that places more demands on the key value (uniquity, etc).

Comment: Just to clarify, the ValueTuple is a new feature in C# 7, native for .Net 4.7. Other classes you could use are Tuple class, KeyValuePair, Dictionary or create your own class

Comment: @Magnetron `ValueTuple` is .NET 4.5 or above, and .NETStandard 1.0 or above; https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ValueTuple/

Comment: only if you dowload the package, thats why I said "native". In .Net 4.7 it's included, and you don't need to install any aditional dlls.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Building on Marc's

```
List<(DateTime when, double value) list = info[0].Zip(info[1], (d,v)=> (d,v));
```

And as Magnetron points out, if you don't have C#7 yet,

```
var list = info[0].Zip(info[1], (d,v)=> Tuple.Create(d,v));
list.Sort((x,y) => x.Item1.compareTo(y.Item1));
```